# Python command line args format issue

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

I am a beginner at Python. Below is the testing code for Python's command line args. If executing from command line with different parameter formats, I get different results, but it feels strange, can anyone help me understand why?

```
1, $test.py d:\     --> this seems ok for os.walk call
2, $test.py 'd:\'   --> this will cause nothing output
```

BTW: I used Python 2.7.3

Test code:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    argMock = 'D:\\'

    path = len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] or argMock
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            print name
```

Comment: Could you try `$test.py 'd:'` or `$test.py 'd:\valid_folder'`? It could be a shell issue. (I don't have a window cmd line to test it.)

Comment: Try `$test.py 'd:\\'` . First backslash escapes next character ('), so the string is unterminated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I just tested, but got the same problem. $test.py 'd:\folder' got none output; $test.py d:\folder got the right ouput.

Comment: hi Jakub M. thanks for your reply, but got the same problem: $test.py d:\\folder output right content; $test.py 'd:\\folder' ouput nothing.

Comment: At a guess, the single quotes are *included* in the path name. I'm not familiar with your shell or OS, but your last comment points that way. Try stripping single quotes on both sides of path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maresh and Jakub's answers are incorrect.

The command line argument d:\ will become the string "d:\".
The command line argument 'd:\' will become the string "'d:\'".

Running the following with input 'D:\':

```
print sys.argv[1] # $test.py 'D:\\'
print argMock
```

yields:

```
'D:\\'
D:\
```

The issue is that putting quote marks around something that is already considered a string will just include the quote marks as part of the string.

Comment: But another issue: if I wanna input a arg with blank space in it. how can handle it. for example 'code' $test.py 'D:\test folder\folder'  `code`

Comment: Use double quotes. $test.py "hello world". Single quotes aren't used in all languages/shells the same way as in python.

Comment: @mmmdreg Yes, double quotes are correct, thanks for your nice answer.

Comment: @Haibo Is there a reason you unselected this as the correct answer?

Comment: @mmmdreg Actually No! your answer is **Correct**. Yeah I also realized the unselected action, I think maybe it's a misoperation ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't come from your program, it comes from the shell interpretation.

When you write `'d:\'` your shell interprets the backslash as an escaping command for the next caracter. Therefore you must escape the backslash like this: `'d:\\'`

Comment: The shell (using windows cmd) considers the apostrophes as part of the string, which is the actual issue. The backslash would be necessary for argMock = 'D:\\' in his code sample, which he already has.